# Get line number that contains a string

Tags: vb.net, text, numbers, line

How to get a line number that contains a specified string in a text file?

Example text file contains:

> Red
>   White
>   Yellow
>   Green

How to get "Yellow" line number? and can i write a string in a specified line, lets say i want to write a string in line 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a line in a text file, you need to read the lines from the start of the file until you find it:

```
string fileName = "file.txt";
string someString = "Yellow";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
int found = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
  if (lines[i].Contains(someString)) {
    found = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

If you want to change a line in a file, you have to read the entire file and write it back with the changed line:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
lines[1] = "Black";
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim toSearch = "Yellow"
Dim lineNumber = File.ReadLines(filePath).
                 Where(Function(l) l.Contains(toSearch)).
                 Select(Function(l, index) index)

If lineNumber.Any Then 
    Dim firstNumber = lineNumber.First
End If
```

**Edit**: If you want to write a string in that line, the best way would be to replace that line with the new one. In the following example i'm replacing all occurences of "Yellow" with "Yellow Submarine"

```
Dim replaceString = "Yellow Submarine"
Dim newFileLines = File.ReadLines(filePath).
                   Where(Function(l) l.Contains(toSearch)).
                   Select(Function(l) l.Replace(toSearch, replaceString))
File.WriteAllLines(path, newFileLines)
```

Or you want to replace a specific line:

```
Dim allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
allLines(lineNumber) = replaceString 
File.WriteAllLines(path, allLines)
```

Comment: Thanks for all these examples, but i just needed the top one which returned an error no matter how i was trying it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO

Dim int1 As Integer
Dim path As String = "file.txt"
Dim reader As StreamReader

Public Sub find()
    int1 = New Integer
    reader = File.OpenText(path)
    Dim someString As String = Form1.TextBox1.Text 'this Textbox for searching text example : Yellow
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim found As Integer = -1
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step i + 1
        If lines(i).Contains(someString) Then
            found = i
            int1 = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    reader = File.OpenText(path)

    'if you want find same word then

    Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(lines2(int1))
    int1 = New Integer
End Sub
```