# Retrieve specific data in a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file called "Games.txt" that looks like this:

```
Call of Duty: 50
Assasins Creed: 23
Watch Dogs: 140
```

If i want to know the number of "Assasins Creed" How would I get that?

What i have tried so far:

I have tried finding it by knowing the line, length of the string. Then reading that and removing the first 15 charachters ("Assasins Creed:") That would leave me with: 23. But this is a pretty bad way of doing it, and it needs me to know the exact line.

What would a better solution be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could show your code in the question, so that people have a change of correcting it, rather than a general explanation of what you intended to do with your code.

Comment: Go to MSDN and look up String.Split and see if something there might work

Comment: As has already been suggested, `String.Split` (simpler) and `Regex` (more powerful) are excellent options.  If you are having trouble understanding how to use them in your code, you're going to need to show your code and explain specifically what's wrong, what's not working, or what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get the values for "Assasins Creed", with Regex, you can do something like this:

```
Dim contents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
Dim re As New Regex("(Assasins Creed):\s*(\d+)")
Dim m As Match = re.Match(contents)
If m.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine($"The number of '{m.Groups(1).Value}' games is {m.Groups(2).Value}.")
End If
```

**Output:**

```
The number of 'Assasins Creed' games is 23.
```

If you need to retrieve the values for all games, you can adjust the above code to something like this:

```
Dim contents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
Dim re As New Regex("(.+):\s*(\d+)")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = re.Matches(contents)

For Each m As Match In matches
    Console.WriteLine($"The number of '{m.Groups(1).Value}' games is {m.Groups(2).Value}.")
Next
```

**Output:**

```
The number of 'Call of Duty' games is 50.
The number of 'Assasins Creed' games is 23.
The number of 'Watch Dogs' games is 140.
```

**Notes:**

- Remember to replace `filePath` with the actual path of your text file.
- You need to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of your class in order to be able to use the [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) class.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finnaly worked for me. Ive been searching for weeks now, Thank you!

Comment: Also, is there anyway i can get the line where "Assasins Creed" is on?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but that's a different question, which has probably been answered several times. It's important to do some research before posting a question. Here, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9946751/4934172) which has answers to yours.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Ill try to search more before asking

Answer (score 0):

Getting started in this game can be tricky because lots of people expect beginners to do their own research *and understand it* before offering a simple solution and explanation as to why it works. Giving an absolute beginner a regex statement looks more like someone flexing their ego than offering assistance, so if you're looking for a solution that a beginner can not only use, but also have a hope of understanding (and possibly utilise again elsewhere in their code), then the split command could be used like this:

If you Import `System.IO` it be more useful than regular expressions at this stage I believe

```
'Place this at the top of the code block above the Class statement    
 Imports System.IO 'This provides access to File.ReadAllLines (Input/Output)
```

Then you could create a function which retrieves the information you need and returns the result like this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns the game value plus the index in the list
''' </summary>
''' <param name="FilePath">Full path of the file</param>
''' <param name="Game">Name of the game to return</param>
''' <param name="index">(Optional) Index of the position in the list (-1 if not found)</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Function GameValue(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal Game As String, Optional ByRef Index As Integer = -1) As Integer

    'This returns the file as an array of lines
    Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)

    'This loop will iterate through each item in the array
    For i As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
        'This turns each line into an array of name and value (either side of the colon + space)
        Dim Segments() As String = Lines(i).Split({": "}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        'This will bypass any blank lines or lines without ": "
        If Segments.Length > 1 Then
            'This tries to match the first segment against the name of the game
            If Segments(0) = Game Then
                'This handles a successful match

                'Store the index of the position of the game in the list
                Index = i

                'Convert final value into Integer and return result
                Return Convert.ToInt32(Segments(1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'If no correct match for Game is found, 0 is returned
    Return 0
End Function
```

When you want to call the function, you can do this from within a button click for example:

```
Private Sub cmdApply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdApply.Click
    'Specify the filename however you like
    Dim f As String = "C:\ProgramData\game.txt"

    'Specify the name of game however you like
    Dim g As String = "Watch Dogs"

    'Start an index at -1 (This will get modified by the function if the result is found)
    Dim i As Integer = -1

    'Use the function to return process a result (value)
    Dim v As Integer = GameValue(f, g, i)

    Console.WriteLine("Game:  " & g)
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " & v)
    Console.WriteLine("Index: " & i)
End Sub
```

Sometimes, simple things can actually be pretty complicated once you really look into how to do it. And like most things, there's always another way to go about it.

If you try this code you should be able to take out a few things:

- How to make and use a function
- How to add xml tags to functions to make calling them easier to understand
- One method of utilising ByRef to affect the value of a variable declared elsewhere (index)
- How to read a text file and process its contents
- How to split a string into an array for independent processing
- How to convert a string into an integer

Things to note:

- An error will occur if file path or name does not exist
- An error might occur if `Game: xys` value is not a number
- An error will *not* occur if the line does not contain `": "` because we tested for that
- In this case, the game name *is* case sensitive. You could use `Game.ToUpper` and `Segments(0).ToUpper` to convert both values to uppercase when checking if they match if you want to remove case sensitivity